# Why I can not use ORDER BY and GROUP BY at same time

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have simple query like

```
        SELECT sc.* 
        FROM sub_category sc
        INNER JOIN submaterial s ON s.ParentID = sc.Id
        INNER JOIN project_material_suppliers pms ON pms.CateogryID = s.MaterialCategory 
        INNER JOIN suppliers  s ON s.Id = pms.SupplierID 
        INNER JOIN deliverer d ON d.EmailID = s.DelivererEmailId
        WHERE sc.ParentID = p_id AND pms.ProjectID = p_projectId       
        order by sc.OrderIndex
```

In this case it works, but problem is when I want to use `GROUP BY` in same time before `ORDER BY` something like this

```
        SELECT sc.* 
        FROM sub_category sc
        INNER JOIN submaterial s ON s.ParentID = sc.Id
        INNER JOIN project_material_suppliers pms ON pms.CateogryID = s.MaterialCategory 
        INNER JOIN suppliers  s ON s.Id = pms.SupplierID 
        INNER JOIN deliverer d ON d.EmailID = s.DelivererEmailId
         WHERE sc.ParentID = p_id AND pms.ProjectID = p_projectId       
        GROUP BY sc.Id
        ORDER BY sc.OrderIndex
```

Output error which I get

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 147 Column: 11
```

What is wrong here ? Where did I made mistake ?

Comment: Do you really `SELECT sc.*`?

Comment: Yeah, what is wrong with `SELECT sc.*? `

Comment: As other point out, the select sc.* is the root of your problem.  But even in cases where you are not concerned about grouping and ordering, it is a very bad practice.  If the structure of your table/view ever changes - add or drop a column - the logic of any query relying on SELECT * will be broken because you will now be either getting columns you don't expect or not getting columns you do expect.

Comment: Yes, you are right 100%. I agree with you. Better way is to use `COLUMN_NAME`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that you *can't*; you can, but only if you do it properly.

This is a regular situation:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) from emp group by deptno order by deptno;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        10      13750
        20      10995
        30       9400
```

This will fail (as you know):

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) from emp group by deptno order by job;
select deptno, sum(sal) from emp group by deptno order by job
                                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

But, if you include offending column into the `GROUP BY` clause, it'll work - and produce different result as there's a new column you're grouping data by:

```
SQL> select deptno, sum(sal) from emp group by deptno, job order by job;

    DEPTNO   SUM(SAL)
---------- ----------
        20       6000
        20       2020
        30        950
        10       1300
        10       2450
        20       2975
        30       2850
        10      10000
        30       5600

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

Besides, query you wrote - the one that uses `group by` clause - will fail anyway as you can't group by only one column, without aggregating the rest of them:

```
SQL> select * from emp group by deptno;
select * from emp group by deptno
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Comment: Thank you brother :) You are amazing in this field Oracle-PL/SQL :) 
Since I add in select statment
`SELECT sc.*,sc.Id,sc.OrderIndex`
I still have a problem

Comment: You're welcome. As I said: you can't group data by one column and leave other columns out out that clause **or** un-aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not only in `ORDER BY` but also in `SELECT sc.*`, when you use `GROUP BY` you can only `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` grouped columns and rest has to be somehow aggregated. See aggregation documentation [Doc. Aggregate Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035)

Example:

```
SELECT sc.Id, sc.OrderIndex, MAX(sc.some_other_column_example)
  FROM sub_category sc
 INNER JOIN submaterial s
    ON s.ParentID = sc.Id
 INNER JOIN project_material_suppliers pms
    ON pms.CateogryID = s.MaterialCategory
 INNER JOIN suppliers s
    ON s.Id = pms.SupplierID
 INNER JOIN deliverer d
    ON d.EmailID = s.DelivererEmailId
 WHERE sc.ParentID = p_id
   AND pms.ProjectID = p_projectId
 GROUP BY sc.Id, sc.OrderIndex
 ORDER BY sc.OrderIndex;
```